# Using MONTH() in a cell formula converts the cell type to "Custom" date format

Tags: excel

I have a cell that has the formula `=INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+65)&ROW())*MONTH($A$1)/12` where `INDIRECT` references an integer and `$A$1` is a date. For some reason, the `MONTH` part converts the entire cell into a date instead of a number. How do I change the formula to have it return a number in number format? (Manually changing each cell through the ribbon is not an option for me).

Comment: I don't think it is the use of the MONTH function so much as the fact that the only referenced cell (e.g. A1) is a date. This is Excel's way of trying to predict the formatting of the cell with the formula from its contents. Sometimes it is right and sometimes it backfires.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+65)&ROW())` only directs to the cell one column over. Would it not be simpler to place for example `C3` (assuming formula is in `C2`) without the `$` and when you copy through it will change the reference relatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this (and I can't comment till I get 50 rep), but you could wrap the whole thing in a text formula, then multiply by 1:

```
=TEXT(INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+65)&ROW())*MONTH($A$1)/12,"@")*1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use `VALUE` as the result is a numerical answer? This does resolve the issue.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but dates are stored as values, so I thought converting to text and back would more likely solve the issue. If Value works, it is a more elegant solution though.

Comment: It does as far as I've tested. Try it and then you can edit your response for the win :).

Comment: I'll test it when I get home, I'm currently writing VBA on a tablet, via remote desktop, on a bus. This is not wise.

Comment: Yep, I ended up switching it to `VALUE` because I realized I needed to do calculations with it later on. Thanks guys.